# RFID reader read one and the same tag many times

Tags: rfid

I have a RFID reader (CS101). When it starts to scan, it reads one and the same RFID tag again and again. So to read 1000 tags, after the 500th for each uniquely read, it makes a thousant empty 1000 empty turnover already read tags.

What can I do to prevent reading the same tags so many times again?

Answer (score 0):

At the reader level you can look into manipulating the RFID session state.  Impinj has good information on how each session works and how your reader will report tag events:

https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202756158-Understanding-EPC-Gen2-Search-Modes-and-Sessions

You can also programmatically add some sort of dwell time, so your program will ignore the tag for so many seconds or minutes after being seen.